# Extension available for ConfigurationDbContext in identityserver4?

Tags: identityserver4

Are there any extensions available for ConfigurationDbContext where we can customize the Context for any additional fields or indexes while using IdentityServer4?

Is it possible to extend the models made available by IdentityServer4?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are asking about how to customise EntityFramework.DbContexts.Config

You could get some idea from the following code

```
public class CustomConfigurationContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<CustomConfigurationDbContext>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A factory to create an instance of the StudentsContext 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static CustomConfigurationDbContext Create(string connectionString)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConfigurationDbContext>();

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        var context = new CustomConfigurationDbContext(
            optionsBuilder.Options, 
            new ConfigurationStoreOptions());
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        return context;
    }

    public CustomConfigurationDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        var context = new CustomConfigurationDbContext(
            new DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext>(),
            new ConfigurationStoreOptions() 
          );

        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        return context;
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureClientContext(_storeOptions);
        builder.Entity<Client>().HasIndex(x => x.ClientName).IsUnique();
    }
}

public class CustomConfigurationContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<CustomConfigurationDbContext>
{
    public CustomConfigurationDbContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        var context = new CustomConfigurationDbContext(
            new DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext>(),
            new ConfigurationStoreOptions() 
          );

        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        return context;
    }
}
```

`OnModelCreating` you can add indexes and you can also add your customise Dbset into custom configuration dbcontext

Answer (score 1):

You can extend ConfigurationDbContext class like this in **Asp.net Core**:

```
    public class MyNewModel
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
    }

   public class MyOtherNewModel
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public ApiResource ApiResource { get; set; }//<-- This is built-in model for identityserver4.
      public MyNewModel MyNewModel { get; set; }
      public List<ApiClaims> ApiClaims {get; set;} //<-- This will add a "MyOtherNewModelId" field into built-in ApiClaims table.
   }

    public class IdentityProviderDbContext : ConfigurationDbContext
    {
      public IdentityProviderDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions) : base(options, storeOptions)
      { }

      public DbSet<MyNewModel> MyNewModelTable { get; set; }

      public DbSet<MyOtherNewModel> MyOtherNewModelTable { get; set; }

      //...
    }
```

Then we can use following command in console:

```
add-migration InitialDeriveFromBaseClass -context IdentityProviderDbContext
```

You can also manage to extend it in a separate class library like the following:
1- Create a new .net core class library.
2- Change the above `IdentityProviderDbContext` class like this:

```
    public class IdentityProviderDbContext : ConfigurationDbContext
    {
    //TODO: This connecton string will be removed as soon as possible.
    string connectionString = "Server=.;Database=SomeDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

    public IdentityProviderDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options)
        : base(options,
             new ConfigurationStoreOptions()
             {
                 ConfigureDbContext = configureOptions =>
                    configureOptions.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=SomeDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
                                                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(IdentityProviderDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name))
             })
    { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
    //...
    // The other parts are the same as above code snippet.
```

Maybe we should conduct connection string in a more appropriate way (more SOLID friendly). But this is just an example.
3- Add a new class named `IdentityProviderDbContextFactory` to inform Entity Framework how to generate migrations.

```
class IdentityProviderDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<IdentityProviderDbContext>
{
    public IdentityProviderDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConfigurationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=SomeDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

        return new IdentityProviderDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

4- Run add-migration command
And DONE.

If you want to add a field to an existing built-in model, Maybe you should prevent EF to generate `original class model` (in the `OnConfiguring()` or somewhere) instead, introduce a `derived model` (from that `original model`)